# Comparar atributo id com class e dar .show em outra div

Tags: javascript, jquery, div, svg

Estou fazendo um mapa do brasil como svg, preciso que quando eu clicar em um determinado estado ele da um show em uma div diferente que vai ter as informações sobre aquele estado.

Preciso compara a id do path com a class da div e exibir o .show

Segue o código que como estou fazendo e a onde eu parei com a duvida.

```
<div id="mapa">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="590" viewBox="0 0 432 428">
    <path id="acre" data-name="Acre"
        d="M 40.00,152.22
           C 40.00 ..." />
 </svg>
</div>

<div id=acre>
   <p>teste</p>
</div>
```

O codigo em js que tenho acha o path que cliquei e da um alerta mostrando o nome como esta abaixo, mais eu quero que em vez que dar esse alerta ele da um .show em uma div que ja vai estar .hide.

```
    $("#mapa path").click(function(){
        alert('Voce clicou no estado do '+$(this).attr('data-name'));
    });
```

Comment: Essa div mapa, você vai popular automaticamente com as informações ou você tem uma div para cada estado? Bom, agora com a pergunta editada... quais são as div's dos estados?

Comment: E a div que queres mostrar tem ID igual ao `data-name`?

Comment: isso tem id igual.

Comment: Você pode alterar o `id do path para data-id` e utilizar: `$('#'+ $(this).attr('data-id')).show()` ou var `id = $(this).attr('data-id'); $('#'+id).show()` para mostrar a div específica do estado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o [Sergio já mencionou em seu resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56061/2998) você não pode ter `ids` repetidos, então você deve alterar uma das duas abordagem para `class` ou [`data-` (data attributes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Criei um solução empregando `id` no `svg` e `data-` na `div`.

[Acompanhe esse exemplo de implementação. E veja se lhe ajuda](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/FX99f/15/)

No `svg` mantenha apenas o `id`:

```
<path id="acre" class="estado" ... />
```

Na `div` de conteúdo mantenha apenas o `data-`:

```
<div data-name="acre" class="modal-estado" ... ></div>
```

E no evento de `click` no `svg`:

```
$("#mapa path").click(function(){
    // esconde todos os demais
    $('.modal-estado').hide();
    // mostra a div especifica
    $('[data-name="' + this.id + '"]').show();
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#mapa path").click(function() {
  alert('Voce clicou no estado do ' + this.id);
  $('.modal-estado').hide();
  $('[data-name="' + this.id + '"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mapa">
  <svg id="svg-mapa" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="490" viewBox="0 0 220000 194010">
    <path id="acre" class="estado" d="M6610 62120l290 160 1961 869 2186 996 836 418 161 65 2219 450 64 32 707 225 97 32 96 0 1962 482 289 65 1254 289 1447 354 1736 353 515 129 450 97 353 225 772 418 1769 964 964 547 547 289 1222 643 900 450 965 547 160 64 129 65 514 225 2058 900 1158 514 2893 1254 772 322 129 96 160 33 193 96 1222 515 868 385 -32 33 0 64 -32 0 32 64 -32 0 0 32 32 0 0 32 -32 0 -32 65 -32 -32 -32 -33 0 33 0 -33 -65 33 32 32 -32 64 -32 -32 0 64 -96 0 -97 32 -32 32 -32 0 -32 0 0 33 -32 32 -33 0 -32 32 -32 0 0 32 -32 0 0 64 -32 -32 -64 32 0 33 -65 32 0 32 0 32 -64 0 -32 64 -64 0 0 33 0 64 -65 32 0 -32 -64 0 -32 0 -32 0 32 64 0 32 -32 -32 -33 64 0 -32 0 65 -32 -33 -32 33 0 32 0 32 -64 0 0 32 0 -32 -32 32 32 32 0 32 -65 -32 -32 32 0 32 -32 0 -32 33 -32 128 -32 32 0 -64 -32 64 -33 0 0 -32 -32 32 32 0 -32 0 -64 65 0 -32 0 64 -32 32 64 0 -32 32 -32 32 0 -32 -32 32 0 65 -32 32 0 32 -33 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 32 -32 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 32 32 0 -129 65 -32 32 -32 0 0 -32 -32 0 -33 0 -64 32 -64 0 -32 32 0 64 32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -33 0 -64 33 -32 32 -64 0 -65 -65 -96 0 -32 -32 -65 0 -32 32 -96 33 -32 -33 -65 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 0 32 -64 -32 -32 32 -33 33 65 64 -32 64 32 65 0 32 -32 0 -33 32 -64 -32 -64 0 0 64 -64 -64 -65 32 -64 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -65 96 33 64 0 129 -33 0 -32 0 -32 32 0 64 -32 33 -129 32 -32 32 -64 32 -65 -32 -64 32 0 64 -96 0 -32 0 -65 32 -96 33 -32 32 -97 160 -32 97 -96 96 -33 65 -96 96 -97 -64 -128 546 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 0 32 -32 0 0 -32 -32 32 0 -32 -32 -64 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 0 -33 0 0 -32 -64 0 0 -32 -32 32 0 -65 -64 0 0 -32 -33 32 0 -32 -32 -32 -64 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -33 0 -32 -32 -64 0 -64 0 -32 32 0 -32 -65 0 -32 64 -32 -32 -32 32 -64 0 0 -32 0 32 -65 -32 -96 64 -65 -32 -64 -32 0 32 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 0 0 64 -32 0 -64 0 -64 33 0 64 -32 -32 -33 64 -32 32 -32 32 -32 0 -32 65 0 32 0 64 32 0 32 32 -32 32 0 33 -32 32 32 32 -32 32 -64 32 -33 65 -64 32 0 32 -64 32 -65 96 -32 0 -32 97 -64 0 -32 96 -32 0 32 32 -32 97 -65 32 -32 64 0 33 0 64 -32 64 -64 32 -33 33 -64 32 -32 64 -32 0 -32 0 -97 0 -32 32 -32 64 -32 33 -65 -65 -32 0 -160 65 -33 64 33 32 -33 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -65 -64 -64 64 -193 32 -96 65 0 64 -65 64 -96 65 0 32 -322 64 -514 129 32 -97 -64 -64 32 -64 -64 -33 -32 0 -33 0 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 -65 -32 -32 32 -64 32 0 0 -32 0 -32 32 -65 -32 0 -32 33 -32 -33 32 0 0 -32 -64 32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 32 0 65 0 -65 -65 -32 32 -32 -32 0 0 32 -64 0 32 32 -32 0 -32 0 -32 32 -33 -32 33 -32 -33 0 -32 32 -32 -32 32 0 -32 0 -64 32 0 65 -32 0 -33 -33 -32 0 -32 33 32 0 0 -33 32 65 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -33 -32 0 -64 65 -65 -32 -64 -65 -64 32 0 -32 -32 0 32 -64 -64 0 -33 0 -64 32 -32 0 32 64 -64 0 0 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 -64 0 0 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 -64 32 -32 -97 -32 65 -32 -32 -65 32 -64 -32 -32 64 -32 -64 -64 0 0 -33 -33 33 -32 0 32 -33 -32 0 0 -32 -64 32 -64 -32 -33 -32 -64 0 -64 32 -32 -32 -65 -64 -32 64 -64 -32 32 0 0 -32 -96 32 -33 32 33 0 -33 32 -32 -64 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -97 -32 0 -32 -32 64 -32 0 0 -32 -32 32 -32 0 32 -64 -64 0 0 32 -65 -32 -32 64 0 -32 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 32 32 32 -32 0 -33 -64 -32 32 -32 -65 -32 0 -32 65 -97 0 0 64 -32 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 0 32 -32 -32 -65 0 0 -64 -32 32 -64 -32 -96 0 0 64 -33 0 -32 0 0 -32 -161 -32 0 32 0 32 -64 -32 -64 0 0 64 -32 -32 -65 32 -128 -32 -32 64 -33 -32 -64 32 -32 33 -32 -33 -64 65 -33 -65 -64 65 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 -64 -33 0 0 32 -32 -32 0 -32 -64 32 -32 -32 -32 0 0 -33 -65 0 0 33 -96 0 -32 0 -65 -33 -32 33 -32 -33 -32 33 -32 -33 -97 -32 -64 32 -32 33 -32 -33 -32 0 -97 0 0 65 -32 0 -32 0 -32 64 -33 -32 -32 64 -32 -32 -32 64 0 -32 -32 32 -32 33 -65 0 0 32 -32 -32 0 32 -64 0 32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 0 0 32 -32 0 -33 0 -32 0 0 -32 -32 32 0 -32 -32 64 -32 0 32 -32 -64 32 0 64 0 -32 -33 0 0 32 -32 0 -32 65 -32 0 -32 32 -64 32 0 32 -33 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 32 -64 0 0 32 -32 32 -65 -32 -64 0 -32 0 -32 -32 -97 32 -32 0 -32 65 -32 -33 -32 0 -33 33 -96 32 -64 -32 -65 32 -32 -32 -32 -33 -96 33 -33 -33 0 -32 -32 0 -64 -32 -32 32 0 -32 -64 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -64 -129 -97 -64 -32 -96 -64 -33 -32 0 -32 -64 -65 0 0 -32 -64 -32 -418 289 -32 -1383 0 -1221 0 -483 0 -1414 32 -547 0 -675 0 -32 32 -97 65 0 32 32 32 -96 32 -32 96 32 65 -32 32 -65 0 -96 32 0 0 -64 32 -32 -32 -33 32 -32 -32 0 -64 -161 -32 0 0 -64 -65 0 -64 -64 32 -32 -64 -32 -64 -161 32 -32 32 -65 -32 0 32 -32 0 -64 -64 -32 0 -32 64 -33 -32 97 32 0 32 -32 64 64 32 0 33 -32 -33 -64 -64 0 0 -33 32 -32 -32 -64 32 0 32 32 65 0 32 0 0 -32 -32 0 0 -97 64 33 0 -65 32 0 65 -64 32 64 0 -32 -65 -96 -32 -65 32 -32 33 32 32 0 -32 -96 32 0 32 0 32 -97 -32 33 -32 -33 -65 33 0 32 -32 0 0 -32 -64 32 0 -32 -32 -33 -32 65 -33 0 0 -32 -32 0 -32 0 0 32 -64 32 -32 0 -32 64 -33 0 -32 0 0 65 0 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 0 32 0 32 -65 -32 33 32 -65 0 0 32 0 33 0 -33 -32 33 32 0 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -32 64 -32 0 0 32 -32 -32 -65 64 -32 0 -32 32 -32 33 -32 0 32 0 0 32 -32 32 -65 -64 -32 32 -32 32 32 0 -32 32 0 32 -32 -32 32 32 -32 0 32 32 0 65 -32 0 -32 0 0 32 -97 32 0 32 32 0 -32 32 -32 32 -32 33 -64 0 -33 32 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -32 0 64 -64 32 0 -32 -97 64 -64 64 0 33 -32 0 -32 128 -32 0 -32 65 -33 0 -32 64 -128 0 0 32 0 -32 -33 64 -32 -32 0 32 -32 32 -64 161 -32 -32 0 96 0 33 0 32 -129 0 -64 -32 -32 32 -65 0 -32 32 -64 0 -64 64 -97 64 -161 65 -96 64 -32 32 -33 32 -32 129 -32 32 -32 64 -64 65 0 96 -97 0 -96 -32 -32 0 0 64 -65 0 -192 65 -33 0 -96 -97 -65 32 0 65 -32 0 -32 -33 -64 97 -1318 0 -2573 0 0 -64 97 -33 32 -64 0 -64 0 -64 -64 -33 -32 -32 32 -64 64 -32 32 -97 64 -32 -32 -32 -64 -64 0 -129 -32 -32 0 -32 96 -97 65 -32 -129 -64 -129 -64 -64 0 -64 -33 -32 -32 -33 32 -64 -64 -64 0 0 -32 32 -96 0 -65 32 -96 0 -97 32 -64 -64 -96 32 -129 -32 0 -32 0 -97 -64 33 -290 -65 -32 -96 32 -65 -32 -64 32 -32 0 -64 -64 0 -32 -32 0 0 -32 0 -65 -33 0 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 -32 -32 0 -64 -64 -32 32 -32 0 -32 0 -33 0 -32 0 0 -32 0 32 -32 0 -32 32 -97 -32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -128 32 -33 0 -32 -32 32 0 -32 0 0 -32 -32 0 0 -32 0 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 0 0 32 0 -65 -33 33 0 -33 -32 0 -32 -32 0 32 -64 -32 -64 0 -33 -32 -32 32 0 -32 -32 0 0 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 0 -32 -32 0 -32 -64 32 0 -32 -32 0 -32 32 0 -32 -33 0 0 -32 0 32 -64 -32 -32 -33 32 -32 0 -32 -32 0 -322 0 -1864 0 64 -64 32 -129 0 -32 64 -32 97 -32 32 -65 64 -32 32 -96 129 -32 0 -32 -32 -65 -32 -32 96 -32 97 -161 96 -64 32 64 32 0 97 -64 0 -32 64 -32 32 -33 32 -32 0 -32 -96 -32 -32 -32 96 -65 129 -64 64 -64 64 -161 0 -128 33 -65 -33 -64 0 -129 -32 -64 0 -32 32 -32 33 -65 -129 -32 -96 -289 -97 -32 -64 0 0 -129 -32 97 -32 32 -65 -65 -32 -128 0 -65 -32 -32 0 -96 -64 0 -65 -97 0 -128 -96 -97 -32 -193 -33 -96 -64 -32 -64 -97 -64 0 -97 -32 -64 32 -64 0 -33 -32 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 0 -64 -65 0 -96 -32 -32 -33 32 0 -64 -32 -32 -64 32 -32 -129 32 -32 32 -129 -64 -257 -65 -161 -96 0 -32 -32 -65 0 -96 -32 -32 32 0 -32 -64 32 -65 -96 -32 -129 -32 -64 -32 0 -32 0 -65 0 -64 -64 -129 -33 -32 0 0 -64 -64 0 -64 -32 -97 -129 32 -160 -64 -65 32 -128 -64 -97 -32 -32 0 -32 -65 -32 -32 -97 -64 -32 32 -96 0 -65 -32 -128 32 -97 -32 -128 -64 -65 -65 -96 -64 -32 32 -97 0 -96 -96 -97 -97 33 -64 0 -32 -161 -65 -65 -96 0 -32 33 -32 0 -32 -33 -33 -32 0 -96 -32 -64 -96 -97 32 -32 64 0 -64 -129 32 -64 32 0 65 96 128 0 32 0 65 -96 32 -64 0 -97 32 -161 -32 -96 -65 -32 -160 -97 -32 -32 -225 -64 -129 0 -32 -32 -65 -97 -32 -96 -96 0 -97 -97 -32 -128 -96 -32 -97 -97 -193 -193 -64 0 -32 -161 32 0 64 0 97 -32 96 -160 0 -65 65 -64 -65 -64 0 -161 -64 -64 -96 -225 0 -65 32 -32 32 32 32 65 32 -33 32 0 97 97 193 32 32 -64 32 -97 129 -64 64 0 96 32 129 -64 32 0 0 32 0 64 32 0 161 -96 96 -129 0 -32 -64 -129 0 -160 -64 -65 -97 -64 -32 -32 -32 -161 -64 -64 -32 -65 -65 -64 0 -32 -32 -64z"
    />
    <path id="amazonas" class="estado" d="M6610 62120l32 -33 97 -96 161 -193 64 -128 0 -65 -64 -32 0 -96 0 -65 -65 -128 0 -33 65 -128 96 -97 32 -96 0 -32 32 -97 32 0 33 -32 64 -96 64 -32 97 -161 32 -65 129 -96 32 -32 96 -64 32 0 97 0 32 -97 161 -128 96 -33 64 0 33 -32 96 0 97 -64 32 0 64 -32 64 0 97 -32 0 -97 32 -32 64 -32 32 -64 65 0 32 32 32 -32 64 0 65 0 96 -33 161 0 64 -32 0 -32 64 -32 0 32 33 32 64 -64 -32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 32 0 32 -32 0 -64 64 -32 33 32 32 0 64 -96 32 -33 -32 -32 32 -32 32 -96 32 -32 0 -33 33 -32 -33 -96 33 -32 32 0 0 -65 -32 -64 -65 -32 -32 -129 -32 -32 -32 -161 -32 32 0 -64 -32 -64 0 -64 0 -33 0 -32 -97 -96 -32 0 -32 -97 -64 -32 -33 -32 0 -64 0 -33 0 -128 -160 -161 0 -64 0 -129 96 -96 -32 -32 32 -33 -32 -192 32 0 64 -65 0 -32 33 -32 32 0 64 -32 0 -65 32 -128 0 -32 0 -65 0 -32 32 -64 32 32 0 -64 0 -32 0 -65 65 -64 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 0 97 -33 0 -128 32 -32 64 0 0 -33 97 -32 64 -96 32 0 0 -97 32 0 32 -96 33 0 64 -32 0 -65 96 -32 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -32 33 0 0 -65 0 -32 0 -32 0 -32 64 -32 32 32 32 -32 -32 -64 0 -65 -32 -32 0 -64 32 -97 64 -32 -32 -64 32 -32 0 -33 0 -96 -32 -64 0 -129 0 -32 32 -129 32 -64 -32 -32 65 -32 32 -97 32 -32 0 -32 32 -64 0 -65 64 -32 0 -32 33 -96 0 -65 64 -64 0 -32 32 -32 32 -32 0 -33 32 -32 0 -64 0 -32 -32 -65 32 -64 0 -32 0 -97 0 -32 -32 0 32 -32 -64 -96 0 -32 -32 0 0 -33 32 -32 32 -32 32 0 33 -64 64 0 0 32 96 -32 32 -32 33 -129 64 32 64 -32 32 -32 32 -32 33 32 32 -32 32 -65 64 33 0 -33 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 65 0 0 -32 64 0 0 -32 96 64 65 -32 32 0 64 32 32 -64 32 0 0 32 65 -32 96 -65 0 -96 32 -32 0 -32 -32 -33 64 -32 33 -32 64 0 32 -32 97 -96 32 0 64 0 32 -97 64 0 0 64 33 0 32 -64 32 32 0 32 32 0 0 -32 0 -64 97 -32 0 -65 -33 -32 0 -32 65 -32 0 64 32 -32 32 64 32 0 0 -64 64 0 0 -64 -32 -32 32 0 33 32 64 -64 64 0 0 -97 0 -32 0 -64 32 -33 33 -96 96 0 64 -64 65 0 0 -32 -33 -33 33 0 64 0 32 -32 129 32 -32 33 0 64 64 -32 64 -129 32 64 65 -32 96 -32 0 -64 32 -32 65 64 32 -32 -32 -32 128 -65 32 0 0 -32 65 -32 32 -32 64 32 129 -96 32 -65 64 -32 -32 -32 96 -97 97 -32 32 -64 0 -64 97 32 32 32 32 32 0 -64 0 -32 96 0 32 -65 33 -32 32 32 96 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 0 -33 33 0 0 -32 -33 -64 97 -32 0 64 32 -32 0 -64 32 32 32 -32 0 -33 33 -32 64 32 64 -64 65 -32 128 -32 64 -32 65 0 32 -33 32 65 0 32 64 0 32 -32 0 -65 0 -32 33 -32 32 64 0 65 64 0 64 64 33 0 64 -32 96 32 65 -64 32 64 128 -96 -32 -33 32 -32 33 -32 0 32 0 32 -33 97 -64 32 0 32 64 32 33 33 64 0 96 -65 65 -64 64 -129 64 32 0 -64 32 -32 65 32 96 64 32 0 0 -32 -64 -64 0 -96 64 32 33 32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -33 64 0 64 65 33 0 32 32 0 32 64 0 96 -129 65 -64 64 64 64 -32 32 -32 33 32 0 65 32 0 96 0 33 32 0 32 32 -32 0 -65 -65 -32 -32 -64 65 0 64 96 64 33 64 -65 33 -32 -33 -128 -32 -65 32 0 97 32 64 -32 32 0 0 97 32 0 33 -129 32 0 32 32 -32 65 32 128 64 -64 0 -64 32 -33 32 0 33 0 32 0 0 65 64 -32 -32 -65 96 0 97 129 32 -64 0 -65 32 -32 65 -32 32 32 -32 64 32 33 96 -65 0 -64 64 0 -32 96 65 33 32 0 32 -65 64 0 32 0 65 0 32 -64 -32 -64 -33 -33 0 -32 65 32 32 33 32 64 97 32 32 32 32 -64 0 -32 32 -32 32 0 32 -33 33 -96 64 -32 96 -32 -32 -97 32 -32 129 -64 -64 -97 -33 -64 65 0 64 32 64 -32 0 -32 32 -32 -32 -65 32 -96 33 -32 32 -65 96 33 65 -97 32 -32 32 0 64 0 97 96 96 33 32 0 32 64 65 0 32 -64 0 -97 0 -128 32 32 32 32 32 64 0 -193 97 0 32 0 0 65 -64 128 0 64 32 33 32 32 64 -32 97 -33 64 -32 64 -32 32 -32 65 -64 -32 -65 160 33 33 96 -65 129 32 32 65 0 32 -129 32 -32 96 64 33 0 0 -64 96 0 32 -32 -64 -64 64 -33 65 33 128 0 32 -33 65 33 64 128 32 64 64 33 33 -65 32 -32 -32 -64 32 -32 64 64 64 32 32 32 0 129 33 161 -33 32 -96 32 0 64 129 97 -65 64 65 0 160 -64 0 32 -32 32 -64 32 32 65 64 32 97 0 32 32 32 -32 32 32 32 161 33 32 32 0 64 -32 0 -65 32 -32 97 -32 0 -32 -97 -64 65 -129 32 -32 64 32 32 32 64 -32 33 -32 0 -32 0 -33 32 97 32 32 64 0 65 0 -65 64 32 97 33 0 96 32 32 32 0 64 32 0 129 -64 128 -64 97 -129 32 -161 0 -192 64 -65 33 0 225 -1318 225 -1254 707 -3987 354 -2090 450 -2669 321 -1800 -32 -161 32 -64 65 -65 0 -64 0 -193 32 -96 0 -65 64 -32 97 -32 0 -64 -65 -129 0 -193 0 -32 -64 -129 -32 -128 32 -97 64 -128 0 -129 65 -64 0 -64 0 -97 -129 -161 -32 -32 32 -129 -32 -32 -64 -32 0 -32 32 0 32 -64 64 0 -32 -65 -64 -32 -65 32 -64 -96 0 -64 -96 -97 -65 -32 -32 -32 -64 0 -32 -32 0 -32 0 -161 0 -65 -64 -64 -33 0 -128 -96 64 -97 0 -64 -64 -32 -32 0 -33 -64 -128 -97 32 -32 -64 -32 32 -32 -65 0 33 -65 0 -32 32 -32 64 0 -32 -64 32 -33 64 -96 33 -96 32 -65 32 -64 -32 0 0 -64 -32 -32 -33 0 -32 -65 -64 -32 32 -64 32 -97 -64 -96 -32 -32 32 -129 -64 -64 -65 0 -32 0 0 -97 -128 -32 -97 -32 0 -32 -128 -32 -65 -32 -32 -33 -32 -64 -32 0 -65 -96 -64 -33 -64 0 0 -64 -97 -32 -64 0 -96 -193 -65 32 -128 -32 -32 32 -129 -96 -64 -65 -33 -64 -32 0 -32 -64 -32 -32 -97 -129 -32 -32 -32 -64 -257 -225 -32 -33 0 -128 32 -65 32 -96 -32 -547 0 -385 32 -901 0 -1125 0 -386 32 0 32 0 33 64 32 33 64 0 32 -33 32 -64 -64 -64 129 0 32 64 128 32 65 -64 64 -96 32 32 65 -32 32 64 128 -32 65 -32 32 0 32 -33 64 33 32 0 0 64 97 -64 32 -65 96 -32 65 -97 64 65 64 -32 33 -129 64 -32 64 0 0 -64 32 -33 129 33 32 32 64 96 32 0 33 32 64 0 0 -32 64 0 0 -96 129 -65 0 -64 129 0 32 0 0 -64 32 -64 32 0 32 0 32 -65 32 -32 97 -32 32 0 32 32 32 64 65 0 32 33 0 64 32 32 96 64 0 65 193 192 65 65 32 -32 32 -33 0 -64 96 32 65 -32 32 -64 64 32 -32 32 32 97 -32 64 96 0 33 0 64 0 64 -32 0 32 129 -32 64 32 0 -64 0 -65 32 -32 0 -64 65 -32 32 32 64 0 64 32 65 0 32 32 32 0 32 -64 -161 -257 -96 -65 -64 -32 -33 -32 0 -96 65 -65 64 0 32 0 32 -96 -32 -129 -32 -32 -32 -64 0 -97 64 -32 65 0 0 -32 32 -64 -65 -65 -32 0 -96 -64 -65 0 0 -64 0 -32 -32 -65 32 -32 97 -32 -32 -64 -161 -65 -64 -64 96 -64 -32 -65 -32 -32 -257 -225 -33 0 -64 32 -32 -64 -64 0 0 -32 -65 -64 -128 0 -64 32 -65 -32 -32 32 -161 161 -96 -33 0 -64 0 -32 -32 -32 -65 32 -160 -32 -129 32 -225 0 -97 -32 -96 -97 -64 0 -33 65 -96 0 -96 32 -65 32 -64 -32 -32 32 -32 -64 0 -97 0 -64 -97 32 -32 0 -96 0 -129 97 -64 32 -33 96 -32 32 -96 -32 -64 -64 0 -1029 0 -1351 0 -707 96 0 -32 32 32 32 129 -32 64 32 0 -32 32 -64 32 0 129 -96 64 0 65 0 32 -33 32 33 96 0 0 32 65 0 64 0 32 -32 64 32 32 -65 33 0 96 -64 161 -64 64 -65 290 129 32 -32 0 32 32 32 32 -64 32 32 32 32 32 -32 129 32 161 97 0 64 32 -32 965 0 2282 0 2541 0 32 0 0 -64 -32 -33 -97 0 64 -96 -96 -64 -64 0 -32 32 -65 32 -64 0 -32 -129 32 -161 -32 0 -97 0 0 -64 0 -96 65 -65 32 -257 32 -32 64 -64 65 -65 64 0 64 -96 64 -32 65 64 64 -32 32 0 65 64 32 129 64 32 32 129 32 32 32 0 65 32 96 -32 97 96 96 97 161 160 161 0 32 -32 32 -64 64 -32 32 -64 -32 -129 129 -32 128 -97 97 -128 32 -32 64 -65 161 -321 65 -32 96 0 225 96 225 0 161 0 64 -64 97 -257 128 -97 32 -161 65 -96 64 -65 354 -160 64 -129 32 -64 97 0 96 0 97 64 128 129 32 514 32 97 0 257 129 482 64 193 32 64 161 97 65 -32 257 32 96 32 97 129 64 128 32 129 97 193 -33 128 33 129 32 96 32 97 32 675 0 129 32 161 -64 192 -32 386 0 450 32 129 -32 193 1093 -322 1222 1126 1350 1190 483 -129 128 32 32 32 65 65 32 64 32 0 161 -32 32 -65 32 0 64 33 65 -65 0 -32 32 -96 0 -33 64 0 97 -32 96 32 64 0 65 -32 32 0 32 0 32 0 32 0 0 -64 65 -64 0 -97 64 -32 0 -96 32 -33 96 0 33 33 32 -65 64 -32 32 -96 -32 -65 97 33 128 -65 97 -64 32 32 64 -32 32 -32 32 -32 33 32 32 -32 32 -65 32 0 64 -96 65 0 64 0 32 0 32 -32 32 32 32 32 33 32 32 -64 96 -65 129 129 -32 -96 64 0 32 -33 0 33 97 32 32 -32 32 96 32 -32 64 0 -32 32 32 64 65 0 32 65 32 32 -32 32 64 64 0 33 64 64 -32 96 0 32 97 0 0 33 -65 64 33 128 -33 0 -32 33 -32 -33 -32 33 32 64 -32 96 -64 0 0 33 -32 96 -33 0 -96 64 0 97 -64 96 32 32 32 33 64 160 32 32 0 65 33 0 32 32 64 -97 129 0 32 -32 32 0 32 -32 32 0 97 0 64 -32 0 -32 64 -64 33 -97 32 -32 0 -64 0 -32 64 32 32 -32 -32 -65 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 -64 -129 64 -32 32 -97 32 -32 32 0 33 -64 96 -64 -32 -32 64 -65 64 -193 33 33 96 -65 129 0 32 0 32 32 -32 33 32 32 32 -32 65 32 96 -32 64 0 32 64 -32 32 65 0 64 -64 64 -129 32 -161 32 -32 33 -96 -97 -33 0 -32 0 -32 32 -32 32 -129 0 -128 33 -97 -33 -96 65 0 96 -32 0 -65 97 -64 64 64 32 0 32 -32 65 65 -32 96 32 32 64 -32 129 32 0 -64 64 -32 64 -97 97 -96 64 -97 -32 -32 -32 -96 64 -65 32 0 32 33 0 32 32 32 65 -32 32 -65 64 -64 -32 -32 64 0 32 0 0 96 65 0 32 0 0 -64 64 -96 -32 -32 193 -129 64 -97 32 33 65 128 -32 32 0 33 64 64 96 128 33 33 32 0 128 -65 0 -64 32 0 33 -96 0 -33 0 -32 32 -32 64 32 32 0 65 -32 32 0 64 -64 64 -97 32 0 65 -64 96 0 65 -96 -33 0 33 -65 -33 -32 65 -32 96 -161 97 -64 0 -32 0 -32 32 32 96 -32 65 -65 64 -64 96 -64 32 32 33 0 96 -65 0 -32 64 -64 0 -32 65 -64 64 32 32 0 97 0 32 96 -65 97 -96 96 32 32 -32 32 -64 129 0 32 -32 97 32 32 64 0 96 0 33 32 32 64 32 32 32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 0 -32 64 -32 0 -33 0 -32 0 -64 0 -64 32 -32 32 -33 0 -32 33 -32 32 -32 96 -64 0 -33 65 0 32 -64 64 -32 32 -32 65 32 32 0 96 -96 32 -65 65 -96 0 -65 32 0 64 0 64 -32 32 0 65 0 64 -32 0 -96 64 -65 33 -96 64 -64 32 -129 0 -32 32 -97 -32 0 -32 -96 32 -32 0 -32 0 -65 -32 0 0 -32 64 -161 0 -64 32 -32 -32 -64 32 0 0 -97 -64 0 0 -32 32 -161 0 -64 0 -96 0 -65 65 -32 32 -32 96 -32 0 -65 32 0 65 -64 32 -32 32 0 64 -64 32 32 32 -32 33 32 64 0 64 32 97 -64 32 0 32 32 32 32 161 0 32 96 64 -32 33 -96 128 0 64 32 33 -32 32 -65 32 0 64 33 32 -33 0 -32 32 -32 33 -32 0 -32 128 -97 33 33 32 32 -32 64 96 0 32 32 32 -32 0 -64 -32 -129 32 -32 32 0 33 0 32 0 64 -96 32 0 0 -33 0 -64 64 0 65 -64 32 0 96 -32 32 -33 97 0 129 65 0 32 96 0 64 -64 33 -65 32 0 96 65 32 0 32 -33 33 0 96 -64 32 0 0 -64 0 -32 32 -97 -32 0 0 -64 129 -64 32 64 257 161 129 64 96 -32 322 -97 128 0 33 32 96 0 0 65 0 96 32 97 65 128 64 65 96 96 65 97 225 128 193 -32 160 -64 129 32 386 64 64 0 64 97 0 32 322 96 96 65 33 0 64 64 32 161 -32 160 -129 290 32 514 -32 65 -128 96 -33 32 -32 64 -128 129 -32 129 0 64 0 32 128 64 97 129 32 64 64 33 32 128 65 64 96 65 96 96 129 65 32 0 32 32 65 160 0 33 -32 64 32 96 64 33 96 482 161 386 32 257 97 193 32 0 161 0 32 0 32 0 0 32 -32 96 0 65 32 32 -32 64 32 64 64 97 65 96 0 65 -32 128 -97 97 -64 225 32 128 64 65 32 32 0 193 -32 32 -161 129 -128 193 -32 96 -32 64 96 451 -32 192 -32 193 64 97 0 225 64 0 97 -65 96 129 32 32 33 129 32 64 -32 32 0 33 -33 64 -32 96 32 97 -32 193 65 160 0 161 64 65 64 128 0 129 0 128 0 129 64 96 97 65 96 32 32 64 97 32 96 290 0 32 0 32 0 96 -32 0 0 33 32 32 33 64 0 64 96 129 32 64 32 65 65 64 64 0 64 32 0 32 -32 65 32 96 -64 32 0 97 32 64 64 0 -32 64 -64 32 0 33 64 96 -32 32 32 32 32 32 33 0 32 -32 160 97 -32 32 0 129 -32 32 -32 32 32 96 -64 32 0 33 -32 0 -32 96 -65 32 -32 32 -128 65 0 64 32 0 -32 64 -33 -32 -32 32 0 65 -32 64 -32 0 -32 32 32 97 -32 32 0 32 -32 32 32 64 0 65 32 32 64 64 0 64 -64 0 0 33 32 32 32 64 0 32 -32 32 -32 0 -32 32 -32 0 -33 0 -32 0 0 65 -64 32 -32 -32 0 32 -97 0 0 32 0 64 32 0 33 32 -33 33 -96 -33 -32 33 0 32 -64 32 -33 -64 -32 -33 -32 -32 0 -32 -128 0 -65 -32 0 32 -96 -64 -32 32 0 96 -65 33 0 96 32 0 33 97 -65 32 0 32 32 96 97 65 64 -32 32 64 33 0 32 32 0 -32 64 0 32 32 129 32 32 64 64 33 0 32 32 32 0 32 -32 32 64 32 0 32 33 0 96 129 32 64 65 0 32 65 64 64 0 32 64 -32 65 64 64 97 129 0 64 32 64 0 0 96 129 33 32 32 64 64 32 0 33 32 64 0 64 129 -32 64 32 32 32 32 33 33 64 32 64 0 64 0 97 96 96 97 32 64 97 225 0 96 129 129 32 96 32 161 129 161 64 97 32 128 32 97 129 32 128 0 65 0 64 -32 64 -65 64 -32 97 32 129 32 96 97 289 96 97 32 161 65 160 128 65 97 64 161 257 225 32 32 33 0 0 -129 32 -32 0 -64 -32 -32 -33 -65 -160 -64 -97 -193 0 -96 0 -33 -64 -32 -129 0 -32 -96 -129 -32 -32 0 0 -32 97 -129 32 -32 32 -64 0 -65 -129 -128 -96 -33 32 -64 64 -64 33 -161 32 -96 32 -129 32 -32 32 -32 -32 -97 32 -64 32 -64 33 -32 -33 -65 -32 -32 0 -32 65 -32 -65 -65 0 -32 32 -32 97 0 32 -64 0 -129 -32 -64 -64 -64 0 -33 0 -64 -65 0 -32 -32 32 -129 -32 -96 32 -32 0 -97 97 -64 0 -161 64 -64 0 -32 -32 -32 0 -129 0 -96 64 -161 97 -65 160 -128 33 -65 0 -96 64 -96 32 -33 96 0 33 -32 0 -32 0 -64 96 0 64 -64 129 -65 32 -32 65 -32 96 32 129 -129 64 0 32 0 225 -32 32 -32 0 -96 32 -32 -32 -65 0 -64 32 -32 33 0 64 32 96 0 97 32 0 -32 32 -32 96 -32 33 32 32 32 96 -32 32 0 129 64 32 129 32 32 65 0 32 0 128 64 129 0 64 0 32 -32 33 32 32 0 32 -32 64 0 32 129 -32 32 0 128 32 0 0 65 129 128 96 -64 33 32 32 32 0 65 0 32 32 96 161 0 64 32 0 161 0 32 0 32 32 0 32 33 32 32 33 -32 32 64 -32 64 -33 32 0 33 97 32 -32 64 32 32 -32 64 32 65 32 32 -32 64 96 -32 97 64 32 -32 161 64 32 0 -32 65 32 32 64 -64 97 -33 0 -32 32 0 32 -32 32 0 97 32 0 -96 160 64 0 32 65 0 32 32 32 0 129 -128 0 -32 -65 -32 65 -65 32 0 32 -64 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 64 -64 32 0 65 0 96 0 32 32 32 -32 32 -32 65 -32 96 0 32 -65 97 0 32 0 32 -32 129 -64 32 0 32 -64 0 -97 -32 0 32 -96 -64 -65 0 -96 -32 0 -32 0 -65 -64 -32 -32 -32 -65 -64 -32 0 -64 -65 32 -32 -64 32 -33 0 -64 -64 -32 0 -32 -32 -193 64 -32 0 -32 32 -65 0 -64 193 -129 0 -64 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 32 -33 32 -96 65 -32 0 -32 32 -65 -32 -96 0 -32 96 0 0 -129 32 -32 32 -32 -96 -129 32 -32 32 -129 -32 -96 32 -32 32 32 65 -32 32 -64 0 -65 32 -32 64 32 -32 -64 97 -97 32 0 32 -64 -32 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 32 -65 32 -64 64 -129 0 -128 129 -129 -32 -32 64 0 64 -96 97 -32 -32 -65 32 -32 0 -32 0 -64 64 -65 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -64 96 -97 0 -32 161 -64 64 -32 65 -65 32 -321 64 -161 2862 0 1125 0 1415 0 0 1350 0 33 32 64 0 128 32 33 32 0 65 64 -33 289 33 32 0 65 -97 193 0 160 32 161 32 0 0 65 0 32 -32 64 0 225 129 97 129 64 0 32 96 0 0 32 32 -32 64 32 65 97 96 32 32 96 33 0 32 32 -32 161 32 129 32 32 32 64 0 97 0 32 -32 64 -64 0 0 97 32 32 0 96 -32 32 0 65 64 64 0 32 32 0 32 129 0 32 97 32 96 96 0 33 32 32 32 -32 65 32 96 193 64 32 65 0 0 32 64 64 32 0 0 33 32 32 0 32 193 128 0 33 32 0 33 -33 32 33 32 -33 0 65 32 64 32 0 32 64 32 0 0 -32 33 0 128 97 0 32 -96 32 32 64 -32 97 128 96 0 65 65 32 0 32 0 32 -32 32 -33 64 33 33 -33 96 65 64 32 0 32 0 32 0 32 32 97 97 0 129 32 32 0 32 32 32 32 -32 32 96 97 33 -32 64 257 -32 0 -32 64 0 65 128 128 32 97 161 64 32 96 129 33 -32 128 -161 32 -32 0 -97 129 -32 64 -64 -32 -32 32 -65 193 -128 32 0 65 32 32 64 0 32 32 97 129 32 32 32 0 64 -32 97 64 64 0 97 -32 32 -97 289 0 97 -32 32 0 64 0 64 64 65 65 0 -32 32 0 64 96 32 0 97 32 0 64 -32 97 32 32 32 -32 64 32 32 32 -32 32 64 97 -64 64 0 97 32 0 32 96 33 0 32 32 0 32 96 33 32 32 65 32 0 32 0 0 64 0 32 32 0 64 -32 65 32 0 -32 96 32 64 -32 0 161 33 64 32 64 -32 65 64 0 64 96 97 -64 32 32 193 -32 0 -32 32 -32 64 64 -32 32 32 64 32 -32 97 64 64 0 32 0 32 97 65 0 -32 129 96 -65 32 65 32 32 65 -32 0 64 32 64 193 -64 0 32 -32 64 64 33 64 -97 65 0 0 64 32 33 32 0 0 64 -64 32 32 64 96 -64 97 96 64 -32 -32 -64 96 32 97 64 32 -96 128 0 0 32 33 0 32 -64 0 -32 32 0 32 32 -32 32 32 32 64 32 33 0 32 -32 64 -32 32 64 32 0 32 -32 33 64 64 -64 0 32 -32 129 32 32 0 32 64 0 97 0 64 129 96 -97 65 65 0 32 0 32 64 32 32 32 0 32 -64 65 32 96 64 65 97 225 32 32 193 -32 32 64 64 64 33 97 32 32 193 32 32 0 32 32 96 64 97 129 64 32 64 0 193 0 129 -64 64 0 65 64 32 32 32 97 0 96 0 32 -32 97 -97 96 -96 129 0 129 32 32 64 0 97 32 96 32 32 64 97 65 128 0 97 -33 64 0 32 33 33 -33 32 -128 0 -32 64 0 32 32 64 -32 33 -65 96 -32 64 -64 32 0 65 0 128 161 33 -32 64 -33 64 -32 32 32 65 65 64 0 96 -65 33 -64 64 -32 96 32 97 0 64 -32 32 -97 32 0 0 -64 33 -32 64 -32 129 -32 128 -161 97 32 32 -32 32 -32 32 -32 64 0 65 0 64 0 225 -65 0 32 -32 65 -161 257 -129 225 -128 129 -129 96 -193 129 -321 161 -161 32 -96 64 -33 32 -96 225 -32 65 0 96 -32 64 -193 258 0 32 32 32 96 32 65 32 64 0 32 32 -128 290 -258 578 -257 515 -161 418 -353 772 -547 1221 -32 33 -193 450 -354 803 -128 322 -193 450 -322 708 -1093 2379 -1415 3087 -321 771 -418 901 -740 1672 -1897 4212 -32 64 -64 32 0 32 -33 0 -128 0 -32 32 -32 161 -33 64 -64 97 -96 32 -258 225 -96 161 -97 96 -64 129 0 418 64 96 33 161 128 354 129 161 64 32 32 96 33 0 128 32 64 65 65 64 160 289 97 97 96 32 33 0 64 129 32 64 64 32 33 129 96 96 64 257 -32 193 32 161 0 64 97 129 64 64 -32 33 -161 160 -161 322 -32 161 -32 160 32 129 32 161 33 64 0 96 -161 161 -65 129 -128 128 -32 33 0 128 0 65 -65 96 -160 161 -193 96 -32 65 -33 0 0 64 65 64 0 225 96 161 97 129 32 128 0 65 32 96 128 225 33 64 -33 97 33 96 -33 65 -128 64 -32 96 64 193 -64 97 32 193 -32 64 0 64 32 32 32 97 -32 32 -129 64 -32 65 32 64 -32 64 0 65 -128 160 -33 65 -64 96 -32 32 -64 129 32 96 32 65 0 64 -32 129 64 64 32 64 0 64 -32 33 -32 96 -32 64 -129 290 32 32 97 32 128 -64 33 0 128 -32 129 64 0 32 -32 32 -97 65 -193 192 -64 65 -32 0 -32 0 -33 0 -64 32 -289 32 -2830 0 -128 0 -3473 0 -2669 -32 -1543 0 -418 0 -64 0 -3473 0 -32 0 -64 0 -97 -193 -32 -32 32 -97 -32 -32 -64 -32 -32 -32 -97 -32 -128 32 -33 -32 -32 -97 -64 32 -64 0 -33 65 33 32 -33 32 0 32 -64 32 0 33 -64 64 -65 -32 -96 0 -96 -65 -33 0 -32 65 0 160 -64 65 -32 64 32 64 -32 32 0 33 0 96 -97 64 -96 0 0 65 -96 0 -65 32 -193 -64 -32 32 -32 -32 0 -97 -64 -96 -65 -33 -64 -128 -96 0 -97 0 -128 64 -129 -32 -129 -321 0 -33 32 -64 -32 -32 -64 -32 -32 -65 32 -64 -64 -96 -97 -65 32 -32 97 0 0 -64 -32 -64 -33 -97 -64 0 -128 0 -65 -64 -128 -32 -32 32 -65 32 -32 32 0 64 97 97 -33 64 -32 0 -225 -161 -32 -32 0 -32 64 -96 32 -65 -64 -64 32 -96 -32 -65 -64 0 -32 -32 -33 -64 0 -97 -32 -128 32 -129 33 -64 0 -64 -33 -33 -64 -32 -64 -32 -64 0 -129 -32 -64 -32 -32 -64 -65 -65 -32 32 -32 0 -32 65 -65 32 -96 96 -32 0 0 -32 -32 -32 -32 -64 -65 0 32 -65 -32 -64 0 -64 -32 0 32 -65 -32 -96 -32 0 -32 -32 -32 0 -33 -32 -32 32 -32 -32 -32 -65 -193 -96 -32 -32 32 -32 -64 -129 -65 -32 -32 -64 0 -33 0 -32 32 -32 33 -64 -33 -32 -32 -97 32 -32 -64 -64 0 -33 -96 -64 -65 -64 -96 -97 -193 -96 -129 0 -32 -64 -64 -97 -32 0 -32 -32 -33 0 -64 -64 -2186 0 -804 0 -161 0 -418 -32 -32 225 32 64 -32 64 -64 32 -32 97 -97 64 0 64 32 33 -32 96 -32 32 -96 161 -161 97 -97 96 0 32 129 225 -129 97 -64 96 0 64 -64 97 -33 32 -32 0 -160 -129 -97 -32 -96 -32 -32 0 -65 0 -32 64 -64 97 -32 32 -97 -32 -64 32 0 289 -161 97 0 64 129 32 64 65 0 64 -161 129 0 32 32 96 97 97 0 96 64 64 32 0 0 65 -96 160 -32 0 -65 -64 0 -32 -32 -32 -32 0 -32 32 -32 161 -65 32 0 64 -32 64 -32 33 32 32 -96 128 32 129 -193 -32 -32 0 -97 64 -64 0 -64 -32 -32 32 -65 97 0 160 65 129 -33 64 -96 97 0 32 0 32 32 97 0 128 32 225 0 65 -32 32 -128 0 -258 160 -160 -32 -161 32 -65 0 -64 -32 0 -32 64 -161 0 -64 0 -32 -64 0 -257 96 -129 65 -128 32 -65 32 -32 0 -64 0 -129 32 -193 -32 -64 0 -32 32 -64 32 -32 0 0 65 -65 32 -32 32 -64 0 -129 -32 -96 0 -65 32 -64 -97 -32 -32 -64 0 0 32 -129 97 -96 32 -33 0 -96 -129 -32 -32 -65 0 -64 0 -128 32 -129 97 -97 64 -32 65 -32 32 -64 -32 0 32 0 128 -64 225 -33 33 0 32 0 64 33 32 0 129 0 32 32 64 0 32 32 65 -32 32 -32 64 -33 97 0 32 -64 32 0 32 -64 64 -97 0 -64 65 0 64 -64 64 32 65 -64 0 -33 32 -32 32 -32 0 32 96 -64 65 0 32 -32 32 -129 0 -32 0 -32 32 32 64 -64 33 -65 0 -128 96 -65 -64 -96 -32 -32 0 -32 0 0 -65 64 -96 0 -64 -96 -33 0 -32 32 -128 -97 -161 0 -64 0 -33 0 -32 0 -32 -160 -96 -33 0 -160 64 -65 64 -225 129 -32 64 -129 0 0 32 -32 32 -32 0 -96 -64 -129 -64 -32 32 0 32 0 32 0 65 0 128 -32 161 0 32 32 64 64 161 0 65 -32 -33 -64 33 -65 -65 -32 65 -96 32 -32 -32 0 -65 -33 -32 -32 0 -32 0 -161 -129 -64 -32 -96 0 -32 0 -97 32 -96 33 -32 32 -33 64 -32 0 -64 0 -32 0 -33 257 -64 32 -128 258 -33 0 -64 -32 -32 0 -32 64 -64 0 -33 32 -64 64 -32 0 -32 -96 -32 -32 -32 0 -33 -161 -64 32 -32 0 0 -96 -32 -33 -32 0 -97 -96 -64 0 -97 -32 -32 -64 -32 -97 -96 -64 -33 -32 -64 -33 0 -64 -96 0 -65 -32 -160 0 -33 0 0 32 -64 32 -193 0 -96 -32 -32 0 -33 0 -96 64 -32 0 -64 65 -161 -65 -65 0 -64 33 -32 0 -97 -97 -32 0 -96 0 32 97 -32 32 -97 0 -32 0 0 -65 -32 -32 -64 65 -97 -65 -64 32 -32 0 -161 -64 -32 32 0 32 96 65 33 96 0 225 -161 129 -64 129 -129 128 -129 97 -32 64 0 64 0 32 -193 33 -64 96 -129 32 -32 32 -96 -32 -65 64 -289 161 -32 97 -64 64 -97 64 -129 0 -64 0 -64 -32 -32 32 32 32 0 129 -129 97 -1222 -515 -193 -96 -160 -33 -129 -96 -772 -322 -2893 -1254 -1158 -514 -2058 -900 -514 -225 -129 -65 -160 -64 -965 -547 -900 -450 -1222 -643 -547 -289 -964 -547 -1769 -964 -772 -418 -353 -225 -450 -97 -515 -129 -1736 -353 -1447 -354 -1254 -289 -289 -65 -1962 -482 -96 0 -97 -32 -707 -225 -64 -32 -2219 -450 -161 -65 -836 -418 -2186 -996 -1961 -869 -290 -160z"
    />

  </svg>
</div>
<div data-name="acre" class="modal-estado" style="display: none;">
  <p>Estado Acre</p>
</div>

<div data-name="amazonas" class="modal-estado" style="display: none;">
  <p>Estado Amazonas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Sergio e Fernando. Consegui entender como funciona com o auxilio de vocês.

Answer (score 6):

Podes fazer assim:

```
i$("#mapa path").click(function(){
    alert('Voce clicou no estado do '+$(this).attr('data-name'));
    i$('[data-name="' + this.id + '"]').show();
});
```

Dessa maneira ele vai udar o ID da `path` clicada (`this.id`) e usa isso num seletor onde procura elementos com `data-name` igual a essaa ID. Depois aplica o método `.show()` para mostrar a div.

Seria prático usares uma classe de CSS para todas essas divs para poderes também esconder todas quando abres uma nova, ou usar uma div pai para poder esconder todas as `.children()`, ou usar uma flag para saber qual a div que está a ser visualizada.

Exemplo de HTML seria:

```
<div id="info">
    <div data-name="tocantins">Esta é a DIV de tocantins</div>
    <div data-name="bahia">Esta é a DIV de bahia</div>
    <div data-name="sergipe">Esta é a DIV de sergipe</div>
```

e JavaScript para exemplo da flag seria:

```
i$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var visivel = null;
i$("#mapa path").click(function () {
    //alert('Voce clicou no estado do ' + this.id);
    if (visivel) visivel.hide();
    visivel = i$('[data-name="' + this.id + '"]').show();
});
```

Outra coisa que podias fazer é criares uma array com todas essas divs em cache, ou um objeto para mais rapidamente acederes ao elemento.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/vxxb80xk/1

Comment: vou tentar aqui e já posto o resultado.

Comment: Vou reformular novamente minha pergunta, acho que não consegui passar o que eu queria.

Comment: Já reformulei da uma olhada novamente quando puder, abraço.

Comment: @IsaiasAntunes o problema é que não podes ter dois elementos com a mesma ID. Dá-me 1 min e junto exemplo.

Comment: ok pode ser a comparação da id com a class.

Comment: @IsaiasAntunes vê esta exemplo -> https://jsfiddle.net/y104L0uk/ uso a ID do path e juntei `data-name` no div. Podes fazer ao contrário, nesse caso fica assim: https://jsfiddle.net/y104L0uk/1/

Comment: ok funcionou, e como faz para quando clicar em outra a div antiga voltar para hide?

Comment: @IsaiasAntunes essas divs estão dentro de outra div? nesse caso podes esconder todas __antes__ do `.show()` da div que queres. Algo como `$('#minhaDivId').children().hide();`. Ou então podes usar classes.

Comment: @IsaiasAntunes assim: https://jsfiddle.net/vxxb80xk/